# How can I remove the read-only property of an object when I clone/copy it?

Tags: javascript, redux

I want to be able to copy/clone the store state and modify it locally. How can I copy the object and get rid of the read-only property?

```
let a = store.getState();
console.log(a.property) // 'property'
let b = copy(a)
b.property = 'newProperty';
console.log(b.property) // 'newProperty'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is that you can get `state` from store and then spread it into a new object.

Like:

```js
const state = store.getState()

const newState = {...state}
```

Now, you can modify `state` object.

But, if you have multi level objects in state then use `JSON.stringify` and then use `JSON.parse` to parse it.

Like this.

```js
const state = store.getState();

const newState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state));
```

It will make a whole new clone and now you can modify state.

I recommend here using `JSON.stringify` because you can have multi level objects in your state.
And `spread` only do shadow copy.

Answer (score 1):

Copy using

```
let b = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a))
```